# Using JS Code to Access Images in HTML Code for Slider

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a website. In the FTP I made folders js, css, img, fonts, errors. I want to take the JS code and put it in js/slider.js  where the code is the file slider.js

When i do that the slider does not function properly.

I believe the issue is with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>
```

I believe this has something to do with not properly accessing the images class

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
```

I tried, but still does not work:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides").src = "~/index.html/;
```

Also in the javascript code it calls "mySlides" which is defined in the HTML code. So I'm looking to CALL and ACCESS html classes information to retrieve this data.

Desired index.html File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <title>COMING Soon!</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <body>
    <h2 class="w3-center">COMING Soon! Temporary Cover</h2>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>
     <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar_area">          
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right custom_nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li> 
              <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>          
              <li><a href="product.html">Our Products</a></li>                 
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

     <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
      <img class="mySlides" src="img/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="img/2.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="img/3.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="img/4.jpg" style="width:100%">

      <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
      <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

slider.js File:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
    showDivs(slideIndex);

    function plusDivs(n) {
      showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function showDivs(n) {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         x[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
      x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
      x[slideIndex-1].style.height = "500px"; 
    }
```

index.html  File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>COMING Soon!</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>
<h2 class="w3-center">COMING Soon! Temporary Cover</h2>
 <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar_area">          
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right custom_nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li> 
          <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>          
          <li><a href="product.html">Our Products</a></li>                 
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

 <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img/2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img/3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img/4.jpg" style="width:100%">

  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  x[slideIndex-1].style.height = "500px"; 
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for error reports?

Comment: Everything looks good, only one issue what I m guess is your js file positioning. Try putting the script tag at the bottom of body tag. The issue may be are invoking a  function name showDiv with 1 as parameter before your DOM is getting ready.